# Prometheus cannot access remote exporters

Tags: freebsd, raspberry-pi, mdns, prometheus-exporter

I'm trying to set up an IoT network using Prometheus as the monitoring layer, and Avahi as the DNS service. I have Prometheus tracking node-exporter on localhost, but am unable to access either node-exporter or prometheus-mqtt-exporter on another host. When I run `prometheus` with `log.level=debug`, I see the message

```
msg="Scrape failed" err="Get \"http://raspberrypi.local:9100/metrics\": dial tcp: lookup raspberrypi.local on 192.168.0.1:53: no such host"
```

I can ping raspberrypi.local from the prometheus host, and can retrieve the `/metrics` page using `curl`, but Prometheus seems unable to resolve the Pi's IP address.

I'm running Prometheus 2.43.0 on FreeBSD 13.2-RELEASE, and the Pi is running OS 5.10.103, prometheus-node-exporter reports version 0.17.0, and prometheus-mqtt-exporter fails to report a version number.